# VBA, Textbox Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

Olla

I'm using a name manager with a list of employees per department and now I want to lookup the clock number per employee inside my code.

I start with my Combobox per Department (CB_Department) then this lookups a range of employees (CB_EName) per department. I then want to vlookup the employees clock number from a table in excel and directly input it into the userform textbox (TB_ENumber). The reason for this route is because the excel sheet is automatically update from Sql (name and clock number) but in which department that persons works is managed inside the worksheet.

Now the issue is that the codes work for the change from department for the first employee but when I change the employee combo box the textbox doesn't update. Can some please tell me what I'm missing

The code I have to thus far

```
Sub CB_Department_Change()
Dim strRange As String
If CB_Department.ListIndex > -1 Then
   strRange = CB_Department
   strRange = Replace(strRange, " ", "_")
        With CB_EName
            .RowSource = vbNullString
            .RowSource = strRange
            .ListIndex = 0
        End With

        With TB_ENumber
            .Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CB_EName, Sheet4.Range("A2:B200"), 2, False)
        End With

Else

End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: There is something missing in your code. It seems there are two `sub beginnigs` but only one `end sub`. Moreover, you can't have `sub` opening inside the other `sub`. Next, you need to trigger your action with any `Change event` while you (try to) trigger it when form is opening and therefore it works when start. So, show the correct/improved  code to  have for further suppoert.

Comment: HI KazJaw, sorry I accidentally left the private sub in the code. The problem is exactly that I need the trigger the second step with a change event on the second combo box (CB_EName). How would I include that trigger inside the current code?

Comment: add additional trigger for second combo box and place inside the code you want to repeat. Or move that repetable code to external sub and call it from both first and second combo boxes.

Comment: Thanks Kazjaw, I moved the code to a external sub.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kazjaw

```
Private Sub CB_Department_Change()

Dim strRange As String
If CB_Department.ListIndex > -1 Then
   strRange = CB_Department
   strRange = Replace(strRange, " ", "_")
        With CB_EName
            .RowSource = vbNullString
            .RowSource = strRange
            .ListIndex = 0
        End With

Else

End If
End Sub


Private Sub CB_EName_Change()

        With TB_ENumber()
            .Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CB_EName, Sheet4.Range("A2:B200"), 2, False)
        End With
End Sub
```